# How can we show image ads on a video running in web page?

Tags: php, html, video-streaming

I need to provide a facility on an admin panel to insert a slide/image/ad into a video which is running in a webpage.

The admin user will be pushing the slides to the running video and then we need to save the timing and the slide in such a way that later on when this video is run we get the same ads/slides in the video.

Comment: The question is very vague. What streaming tech/server, flash/non-flash, player? But any way checkout pre-roll, mid-roll, post-roll

Comment: Let's say it is HTML5 video tag and a non-flash item.

Comment: How can I do it with flash players? e.g: JWPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

[PopCorn.JS](http://popcornjs.org/) from Mozilla would be ideal for this.

It allows you to show and remove HTML snippets based on the timing of your video.